many angular app with one spring-boot backend oauth2/oidc login
I'd like to deploy angular app independently from my spring-boot backend that handles oauth2/oidc login process. Local setup looks like that
angular (localhost:4200, localhost:4300) <-> spring boot backend (localhost:8080) <-> my company oauth2/oidc server
If the angular app is packed with backend in spring-boot jar everything works correctly as both backend and frontend are on the same url (localhost:8080).
But when i run many angular apps on a diffrent ports there and want to do authentication via backend i have the problem with redirect after login. Basically backend redirects to "/" (what is localhost:8080 in my case) but i want to redirect to angular app url (localhost:4200 or localhost:4300). I made a workaround by setting    oauth2.defaultSuccessUrl
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

...

        return http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) ->
        {
            auth.requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).requestCache(cache -> cache.requestCache(requestCache)).cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).oauth2Login(oauth2 ->
        {
            oauth2.defaultSuccessUrl("/api/login");
...
        }).build();
    }

and creating redirect rest endpoint /api/login
    @GetMapping("/api/login")
    public void login(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:4200");
    }

but in that way i can handle only one angular app instance.
Is there any way i can handle many frontend apps with one spring-boot backend that handles oauth2/oidc process?

I'm surprised that my answer was not even useful.

This is how I proceed:

each frontend provides the URL it wants the user to be redirected to after login in a custom header (X-POST-LOGIN-SUCCESS-URI in my case) or parameter (post_login_success_uri in my case) of the request initiating the login (the one at /oauth2/authorization/{registration-id})
a custom (Server)OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver on the the Spring OAuth2 client configured with oauth2Login saves this URL in session
a custom  (Server)AuthenticationSuccessHandler looks for a saved URL in session, and if it finds one uses it instead of the default one.

All that is available from maven-central as part of spring-addons-starter-oidc.
You can try it with the companion project of this article I wrote. The 3 frontends (Angular, React, and Vue) use this mechanism to authenticate users on the same OAuth2 BFF & authorization server and then return to the right frontend.
P.S.
Disabling CSRF protection on a Spring OAuth2 client with oauth2Login is a huge security breach: requests to such a backend are authorized with a session, which is the vector for CSRF attacks.
